# Constant types in Java vs Swift

Tags: java, swift

I've seen some other answers and I've consulted with my teacher, but I can't seem to get the answer I'm looking for. In swift, if I declare a variable, something along the lines of:

```
var number1 = 1
var number2 = 2
let sum = number1 + number2
number1 = number1 + 1
```

The last line should in turn increase the value of sum by one, assuming I'm remembering correctly. But in java as far as I can tell there is no way to do this. Does anyone know a way? (bottom line being, can I make a variable whose value depends on other variables fluently?

If I've gotten anything wrong with my question let me know, I can rephrase.

Thanks

Comment: The short answer is no, primitive values can't depend on other values. However, you could create wrapper classes and make them dependent on each other. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @MiguelJiménez yeah that helps. Good to know it doesn't exist primitively, I'm still fairly new to the language. Could you point me towards a way to learn about wrapper classes? Does it have something to do with inheritance? Thanks.

Comment: *"The last line should in turn increase the value of sum by one"* - not in Swift (or just about any language). It modifies `number1`, not `sum`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Java nor Swift work like this. `int` in Java, and `Int` in Swift don't keep track of which other values "contributed" to their values in the past.

Answer (score 0):

> The last line should in turn increase the value of sum by one, assuming I'm remembering correctly.

You are in fact remembering incorrectly.

In Swift, updating one of the components of `let sum = a + b` afterwards does not change `sum`. Execution proceeds from top to bottom.

All `let` does is declare a "constant", i.e. a `var` that you cannot change anymore. It is like `final int` in Java.

Maybe you wanted `sum` to be a function/closure? Then it would produce the "current" value whenever you call it.

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the waste of a question.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, this is not possible neither in Java nor Swift.

Based on your comment, I came up with this simple example:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Variable<T extends Number> {
    private Supplier<T> value;

    public Variable(final T value) {
        this.value = () -> value;
    }
    public Variable(final Supplier<T> expression) {
        this.value = expression;
    }
    public T value() {
        return this.value.get();
    }
    public void update(T value) {
        this.value = () -> value;
    }
    public void update(final Supplier<T> expression) {
        this.value = expression;
    }
}
```

This is how you use it:

```
Variable<Integer> a = new Variable<>(10);
Variable<Integer> b = new Variable<>(20);
Variable<Integer> c = new Variable<>(() -> Integer.sum(a.value(), b.value()));
System.out.println(c.value()); // 30
b.update(10);
System.out.println(c.value()); // 20
b.update(() -> Integer.sum(a.value(), 100));
System.out.println(b.value()); // 110
System.out.println(c.value()); // 120
```

Of course, this is not even near your example, but it shows a proof of concept using wrapper classes.

Beware that this implementation could throw a `StackOverflowError` if you have recursive definitions, for example `b.update(() -> Integer.sum(a.value(), c.value()));`.

As you mentioned you're new to Java, you can read more about lambda expressions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). You may also want to read about [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

To complete what others have said, to reproduce the **real** semantics behavior of the above Swift code, you would write.

```
int number1 = 1;
int number2 = 2;
final int sum = number1 + number2;
number1 = number1 + 1;
```

To get something close to your **imagined** behavior, you could write this:

```
int number1 = 1;
int number2 = 2;

java.util.function.IntSupplier sum = () -> number1 + number2;
number1 = number1 + 1;
```

... but you have to use a `sum` as `sum.getAsInt()` to get the current value.   And when `number1` or `number2` are local variables, they must be *effectively final* at the point where the lambda is instantiated.